# Method 'Add' of object 'Sheets' failed, and cannot rename new sheets

Tags: excel, vba, office365

In my VBA project, I frequently make a temporary sheet in the workbook, which gets deleted before the macro exits. The sheet is added as follows

```
temp = "Temp"
ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add(after:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count)).Name = temp
```

This has been going well for quite a while. Now, however, the code returns an error

> Run-time error '1004': Method 'Add' of object 'Sheets' failed

A sheet has been added, although not named "Temp" (instead it's named `Sheetn`).

I can successfully add a new sheet, but get the following error message. I am unable to change the name of the newly added sheet.

> "We couldn't move this sheet"

The workbook is not protected, and there is no other sheet named `Temp` present in the workbook. Because of this, I feel I have encountered an invisible wall that prevents users from adding large quantities of sheets, even though these sheets are deleted.

This puzzles me, any explanations and/or workarounds?

Comment: How many sheets have you got in that workbook and what's the newly created sheet's generated codename?

Comment: 4 sheets. The new sheet does not pop up in the VBA editor, oddly enough. I was wondering if it would have a long code name, but it's not there..

Comment: I have never encountered anything like it, I'll do some tinkering after work. Which Excel version are you running?

Comment: Not a surprise, I cannot find anything like it online. Not even that second error message! Running 365.

Comment: Delete the temp sheet, save, close and try again.

Comment: Consider adding the [tag:office365] tag, someone watching it may have some insight.

Comment: Do you have another "Temp" sheet in there?

Comment: @Error 1004 There is no temp sheet

Comment: Save close and retry. i faced the same problem at the past

Comment: @Nathan_Sav "...and there is no other sheet named Temp present in the workbook"

Comment: @Error1004 That did the trick. Odd error and very annoying if an unknowing user encounters it. Cheers!

Comment: @TimStack does the problem fixed?

Comment: Indeed. Saving and reopening did the trick

Comment: I'm having the same problem. I noticed save/close/reopen works for awhile, but then it crops up again. I think it might be related to the number of temp sheets that have been added during testing reaching some threshold, but I can't figure out why or a sure proof way to stop it from happening.

Answer (score 0):

Having noted from the comment thread that you've solved it by Saving, Closing and Reopening, that @SandPiper has had the same problem recur after a while, and that your OP asks for workarounds, the obvious one that I would suggest would be to stop creating and then removing the Temp sheet, and instead simply create it as a permanent part of the workbook, then hide it, and simply use it when it's needed and clear it afterwards (programmatically).

Answer (score 0):

Having the same problem here and in my case the problem was resolved by temporarily disabling the autosave function. I never had this problem until i started working with 365 version. Any other having this problem on other version then 365?

Microsoft® Excel® voor Microsoft 365 MSO (Versie 2202 Build 16.0.14931.20128) 64 bits